# How to call graphql based on the response of other graphql in react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using the folloing version for the graphql and react.

"react-apollo": "^1.4.10",
"graphiql": "^0.11.2",
"graphql": "^14.0.2",

Following are the snippet for the graphql call inside the compose function.
I want to call graphql using async await so the second call will wait till the response will come from the 1st one.And third graphl call will only after the second call.

How can we achieve into the following code.

```js
export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
  ),
  graphql(call1, {
    options: props => {
      return {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables: { id },
      };
    },
    props: ({ data }) => {
      return data
    },
  }),
  graphql(call2, {
    options: props => {
      return {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables: { firstcallid },
      };
    },
    props: ({ data }) => {
      return data
    },
  }),
  graphql(call3, {
    options: props => {
      return {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables: { based on the graphql 1 and graphql call 2  },
      };
    },
    props: ({ data }) => {
      return data
    },
  }),
)(Component);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using `.then`

```
export default compose(
      withRouter,
      connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
      ),
      graphql(call1, {
        options: props => {
          return {
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
            variables: { id },
          };
        },
        props: ({ data }) => {
          return data
        },
      }).then((res)=>{
          graphql(call2, {
        options: props => {
          return {
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
            variables: { firstcallid },
          };
        },
        props: ({ data }) => {
          return data
        },
      }).then((res)=>{ graphql(call3, {
        options: props => {
          return {
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
            variables: { based on the graphql 1 and graphql call 2  },
          };
        },
        props: ({ data }) => {
          return data
        },
      })
      })
      })
    )(Component);
```

You can also check field of `res` object that you receive after the calls if there's a condition to be met!